# Docker swarm: How to manually set node names?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, service-discovery, consul, docker-swarm

**For some background on my environment:**

I have docker swarm running on 3 ubuntu 14.04 vagrant boxes.  The swarm master is running on 1 machine (with consul) and the other 2 machines are running swarm workers that are joined to the master. I set up the environment following the documentation page https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-manual/.  It is working correctly so that any `docker -H :4000 <some_docker_command>` run from my master machine works fine. Service discovery is active as I am running the **gliderlabs/registrator** container on both of my workers. Any changes to my cluster, such as a node or container failure, are shown by swarm within about 30 seconds (which is a bit slow in my opinion, but at least its working).

**The issue:**

Swarm recognizes both of my nodes as "ubuntu-14"

```
vagrant@ubuntu-14:~$ docker -H :4000 ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                        NAMES
a6972155d243        cohenaj194/apache-simple   "/usr/sbin/apache2ctl"   About an hour ago   Up 13 seconds       172.28.128.6:32770->80/tcp   ubuntu-14/test2
af78a8c788ed        gliderlabs/registrator     "/bin/registrator con"   2 hours ago         Up About an hour                                 ubuntu-14/registrator2
8e39416a785a        gliderlabs/registrator     "/bin/registrator con"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours                                       ubuntu-14/registrator1
27c2225b32fb        cohenaj194/apache-simple   "/usr/sbin/apache2ctl"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          172.28.128.4:32770->80/tcp   ubuntu-14/test1
vagrant@ubuntu-14:~$ docker -H :4000 network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER
38b24dc5615b        ubuntu-14/bridge    bridge              
c4e1ffae2fa7        ubuntu-14/bridge    bridge              
29cf499e57ab        ubuntu-14/host      host                
7b4a4a153ada        ubuntu-14/host      host                
723b6bc6f23c        ubuntu-14/none      null                
01f3647d62cd        ubuntu-14/none      null
```

I would like to know how to manually change the name of my nodes from "ubuntu-14" to something else.  I would prefer to be able to set the tags by adding a line to the `/etc/default/docker` file, as the private cloud I will eventually be running my cluster within does not have a way to set instance tags similar to other cloud providers such as AWS.

**tldr:** I have 3 vagrant ubuntu boxes running swarm (1 master + 2 workers).  The workers by default have the tag name "ubuntu-14" and I want to manually change that by adding something to the `/etc/default/docker` file on each worker.  What do I add?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### The solution

```bash
## change the hostname
hostname myname
## restart docker
sudo service docker restart
```

I just changed the hostnames of my vagrant boxes by editing the `/etc/hostname` file and changing ubuntu-14 to master, worker1 or worker2.  Then I restarted my machines and also had to restart the docker services on each machine with `sudo service docker restart`. I also destroyed my old containers and ran them again I'm not sure if this step is necessary, but I did it for good measure.

Comment: restarting the docker service is the answer.  It is not necessary to restart the machine.

Comment: I think you don't even need to do that, just `sudo hostnamectl --no-ask-password set-hostname [NameYouWantToChangeTo]`

Answer (score 1):

this solution works for me

### change the hostname (until reboot)

```
hostname myname
```

### permanent hostname change

```
hostnamectl set-hostname myname
```

### restart docker

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```