# Why are two docker swarm nodes getting the same name?

Tags: docker-swarm-mode

I'm a Docker swarm mode noob going through the tutorial at https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial and noticed when I hit the chapter on draining nodes (https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/drain-node/) that both of my worker nodes were given the same name, `moby`:

```
matthew@bunty:~$ docker node ls
ID                           HOSTNAME  STATUS  AVAILABILITY  MANAGER STATUS
3vkklry19mesmsjrgltj53kap    moby      Ready   Active
biur2a68tze2oykta9klklkeq    moby      Ready   Active
daf8npyma8r0dnmcxu6j491jq *  bunty     Ready   Active        Leader
```

That makes issuing the drain command fail:

```
matthew@bunty:~$ docker node update --availability drain moby
Error response from daemon: node moby is ambiguous (2 matches found)
```

If I use the ID, the command works.

I saw [Docker swarm: How to manually set node names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535185/docker-swarm-how-to-manually-set-node-names), but my environment is different.  My manager node is an Ubuntu box with hostname `bunty`, and my workers are a Windows box with hostname `VADER` & my MacBook Pro with hostname `newt`. All are running the latest version of Docker 1.12.x.

I expected the node names to be `bunty`, `VADER`, & `newt`, respectively, but instead I get `bunty` for the manager & `moby` for both workers.

What gives?  There doesn't appear to be an option in the `docker swarm join` command that lets me manually name the node, and each worker has a unique hostname.